# Tem como passar uma classe como parâmetro no Flutter?

Tags: flutter

Olá, pessoal. Beleza?
Estou iniciando no Flutter, e estou fazendo um menu dinâmico através de uma chamada REST que me retorna um JSON com o titulo do botão e a tela que ele deveria abrir.

Logo, eu faço um loop criando os botões, mas eu preciso passar no onPressed do botão o que ele deve fazer, que no meu caso seria abrir uma tela.

Tem como passar uma classe por parâmetro para eu utilizar com o MaterialPageRoute?

```
Widget _criarBotao(String titulo, BuildContext context) {
return Padding(
  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10, bottom: 10, left: 20),
  child: TextButton(
    onPressed: (
        //Queria aqui passar o evento com a chamada da classe
        ) {
      Navigator.push(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) => PessoaPage(),
          ));
    },
    child: Text(
      titulo,
      style: const TextStyle(
        fontSize: 15,
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

}

Ou talvez existe uma forma melhor de fazer isto? Como mencionei, estou iniciando no Flutter, qualquer ajuda é super bem vinda.

Comment: Oi Gustavo. O ```onPressed``` desse botão recebe um voidCallback e portanto é uma função que não aceita parâmetros. Ele também é chamado automaticamente quando o usuário toca no botão, então seria difícil chamar você mesmo para passar a classe que você quer. Como você sabe como discernir cada botão da lista? Você precisa usar a mesma informação para discernir também a ação. (Não dá pra ver pelo código, mas por exemplo ```if (titulo == 'tela1')[...]push Tela1()``` serviria?)

Comment: @Naslausky, isso mesmo amigo, eu tenho uma lista que eu tenho o titulo e o nome da tela. Eu pensei em fazer uma função que retorna a classe da tela no momento de criar o botão. Essa é minha lista `botao['titulo'] = 'Pessoa';
    botao['rota'] = 'pessoa_page';`

Comment: Vou tentar usar da maneira como sugeriu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No seu caso específico de querer passar uma tela para dar push, você pode utilizar a funcionalidade de [rotas nomeadas](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/navigation/named-routes):

O seu aplicativo tem como widget pai um `MaterialApp`, correto?
Nele, você pode declarar todas as rotas possíveis que seu aplicativo pode fazer:

```
MaterialApp(
  title: 'Titulo Do APP',
  initialRoute: '/',
  routes: {
    '/': (context) => const TelaInicial(),
    'pessoa_page': (context) => const PessoaPage(),
    'animal_page': (context) => const AnimalPage(),
  },
)
```

E aí, quando você quiser chamar a tela, pode utilizar o método `Navigator.pushNamed` e passar só o nome da rota que você deseja.

(Não acho que seja muito elegante, mas note que eu dei o nome das rotas exatamente o que o seu `botao['rota']` retorna. Assim podemos chamar diretamente dentro do método)

Ao criar o botão, você ainda precisa saber qual página ele direciona, então sua função precisaria receber dois parâmetros (ou o seu mapa diretamente). Com essa alteração, segue um exemplo utilizando o `Navigator.pushNamed`:

```
Widget _criarBotao(Map botao, BuildContext context) {

return Padding(
  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10, bottom: 10, left: 20),
  child: TextButton(
    onPressed: () => Navigator.pushNamed(context, botao['rota']),
    child: Text(
      botao['titulo'],
      style: const TextStyle(
        fontSize: 15,
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

Para mais informações, sugiro ler o cookbook que coloquei no começo da resposta. (Em inglês.)

Answer (score 1):

No seu caso, a "classe" que você deseja passar como parâmetro pode ser entendido como um *Widget*, dessa forma basta você criar um parâmetro em sua função com esse tipo específico.

```
Widget _criarBotao(String titulo, BuildContext context, Widget pagina) {
return Padding(
  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10, bottom: 10, left: 20),
  child: TextButton(
    onPressed: (
        //Queria aqui passar o evento com a chamada da classe
        ) {
      Navigator.push(
          context,
          MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) => pagina,
          ));
    },
    child: Text(
      titulo,
      style: const TextStyle(
        fontSize: 15,
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
}
```

Para utilizar basta fazer

```
_criarBotao("perfil", context, PerfilPage());
```

Só lembrando, não conseguimos transformar uma string em uma classe... Então você vai ter que tratar com *ifs* ou um *switch-case*, para saber qual *Widget* informar na chamada da função de criar botão.

Comment: obrigado pela resposta! Vou tentar implementar.